# Combine datepicker and timepicker values with ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I am using `ngx-bootstrap` in an Angular 5 project.
Does anyone know how to combine the [Datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker) with [Timepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker)? When I select a time it always includes today´s date. I want to use the date selected in the `Datepicker`.

Even better would be to have it on the same model if possible.
The idea is to pass this into a `webapi` which accepts a `datetime` property(c#).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both the values of Datepicker and Timepicker will be of type [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

So you can simply combine their values before sending the result to the server.

For example, assuming that you stored the value of Datepicker inside a `date` variable and the Timepicker inside the `time` variable, you can do the following:

```
date.setHours(time.getHours(), time.getMinutes(), time.getSeconds());
```

now `date` contains both the date from the Datepicker and the time frome the Timepicker, so you can now send `date` to the server (in whatever format you need).

Comment: Its a shame you can't have them pointing to the same model somehow as it could be easy to introduce bugs this way if you forget to do the setHours or you are using the model in other locations.

Comment: @MadMac you can suggest this feature here: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can combine the Date and Time Pickers into a custom [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) and abstract away the need to combine separate date & time values on a per item basis.

The code below is *opinionated* in the sense that:

- It makes both date and time required.
- It eliminates the spinner arrows to create a more "even aesthetic".
- Assumes you want the date field to grow as the view-port grows.

But it can easily be modified and should form a good basis for accomplishing this task.

### Component

```js
// datetime-picker.component.ts
import { Component, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

interface DateAndTime {
  date: Date;
  time: Date;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'datetime-picker',
  templateUrl: './datetime-picker.component.html',
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => DatetimePickerComponent),
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class DatetimePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  private onChange: (value: Date) => void;

  public datetime: Date = new Date();
  public form: FormGroup;

  constructor() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({});
    this.form.addControl('date', new FormControl(this.datetime, Validators.required));
    this.form.addControl('time', new FormControl(this.datetime, Validators.required));
    this.onChanges();
  }

  private onChanges(): void {
    // listen for changes, and recombinate internal datetime when they occur
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((f: DateAndTime) => this.setDatetime(f));
  }

  private setDatetime(d: DateAndTime) {
    this.datetime.setFullYear(d.date.getFullYear(), d.date.getMonth(), d.date.getDate());
    this.datetime.setHours(d.time.getHours(), d.time.getMinutes(), 0, 0);

    this.onChange(this.datetime);
  }

  /*
   * Control Value Accessor
   */
  writeValue(value: Date): void {
    // This method is called with the `null` value when the form resets.
    // A component's responsibility is to restore to the initial state.
    if (value === null) {
      value = new Date();
    }

    this.datetime = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void { }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void { }
}
```

### View

```html
// datetime-picker.component.html
<div class="d-flex" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="flex-grow-1 pr-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="date" bsDatepicker />
  </div>
  <div>
    <timepicker formControlName="time" [showSpinners]="false"></timepicker>
  </div>
</div>
```